# React tutorial via PluralSight - props is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been following a React tutorial on PluralSight when I ran into an error.  Could be mine, I don't know.

I've been using JS Complete. The tutorial directed me to this URL, which is the starting point:

https://jscomplete.com/playground/rgs2.4

As the tutorial progressed, it led me to the following code:

```
const testData = [
{name: "Dan Abramov", avatar_url: "https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/810438?v=4", company: "@facebook"},
{name: "Sophie Alpert", avatar_url: "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/6820?v=4", company: "Humu"},
{name: "Sebastian Markbåge", avatar_url: "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/63648?v=4", company: "Facebook"},
];

const CardList = (props) => (
  <div>
   {props.profiles.map(profile => <Card {...profile}/>)}
  </div>
);

class Card extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const profile = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="github-profile">
        <img src={profile.avatar_url} />
        <div className="info">
          <div className="name">{profile.name}</div>
          <div className="company">{profile.company}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }    
}

class Form extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <form action="">
        <input type="text" placeholder="GitHub username" />
        <button>Add Card</button>
      </form>
   );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
constructor() {
  super(props);
    this.state = {
      profiles: testData,
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="header">{this.props.title}</div>
        <Form />
        <CardList profiles={this.state.profiles} />
      </div>
    );
  } 
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App title="The GitHub Cards App" />,
  mountNode,
);
```

On the JS Complete site, it prints the error as follows:

```
ReferenceError: props is not defined
at new App 
at constructClassInstance 
at updateClassComponent 
at beginWork$1 
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback 
at HTMLUnknownElement.sentryWrapped 
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev 
at invokeGuardedCallback 
at beginWork$$1 
at performUnitOfWork
```

I would like to say I followed the tutorial exactly as instructed, but maybe I need a set of new eyes. I'm new to React.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to put the props in the constructor method

```
App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {...
```

should be

```
App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {...
```

Comment: Wow. You gotta be kidding me.  That fixed it.  Thanks for being a second set of eyes for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below the updated working code,

Observed that you are not passing the props from  like title and referring from CardList

```
const CardList = (props) => (
    <div>
    {props.testData.map(profile => <Card {...profile}/>)}
    </div>
);

class Card extends React.Component {
    render() {
    const profile = this.props;
    return (
        <div className="github-profile">
          <img src={profile.avatar_url} />
        <div className="info">
          <div className="name">{profile.name}</div>
          <div className="company">{profile.company}</div>
        </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <div className="header">{this.props.title}</div>
        <CardList testData={this.props.data}/>
        </div>
    );
  } 
}
const testData = [
    {name: "Dan Abramov", avatar_url: "https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/810438?v=4", company: "@facebook"},
    {name: "Sophie Alpert", avatar_url: "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/6820?v=4", company: "Humu"},
    {name: "Sebastian Markbåge", avatar_url: "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/63648?v=4", company: "Facebook"},
];
ReactDOM.render(
    <App title="The GitHub Cards App" data={testData}/>,
  mountNode,
);
```